# Crazy Font Issue with NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, macos, fonts, nstextview, core-text

I'm knee deep in font metrics with NSTextView at the moment.  I was hoping a developer here could shed some light as to what's going on.

With Myriad Pro in a default NSTextView (dragged from IB and run in a fresh project), here's what you get:

[image: selected text]
[image: unselected text]

Notice how the selected rect has the same height as the insertion point.

Now for behavior from Pages:

[image: unselected pages text]
[image: selected pages text]

Notice how the selected rect is similar to the regular text view version, but the insertion point height is actually more reflective of the font (and smaller!).

Weird.

Why do I care?  Here is a screen of my application with Helvetica, and then with Myriad:

[image: My App Helvetica]
[image: My App Myraid Pro]

Notice that in both cases, the outline symbol is perfectly centered with the insertion point height.  Those symbols are actually subviews, and not in the text stream.  Notice those symbols in Pages.  They remain centered for Myriad.  Clearly Apple realized something and fixed it.  Any ideas what they did?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a mistake on Apple's part but rather an assumption on yours. This is a function of font metrics as well as line height.The insertion point takes the whole line height; the drawn font parts don't.

I thought it was you who I pointed to the [Font Handling guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/FontHandling/Tasks/GettingFontMetrics.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000439-DontLinkElementID_16) a few days ago. Either way, you need to understand this topic thoroughly so you can determine where to draw your dot.

Comment: In the case of pages, the insertion point for Myraid pro is smaller than the whole line height.  That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: Currently, if I make the dot view the same size as the cap height, and offset it from the glyph rect by (baselineoffset - capheight), it seems to work.  I just want to know how apple cleaned up their insertion point.

Comment: Good point but you can't really go by Pages' implementation since its UI does a lot of custom stuff. You need to go by TextEdit's behavior since it uses the stock NSTextView. I wouldn't be surprised to see a future NSTextView update that disregards line height when drawing the insertion point but I wouldn't hold my breath, either. :-)